# Responsive UI in Flet

Tags: flet

I'm getting to grips with Flet, which seems easy enough. One thing I want to know is does it provide functionality for scalable UIs?

As in, develop an app on desktop for mobile use, but without knowing the screen size it will be deployed on, so rather than using absolute values for widget sizes, use proportions (or percentages)?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Flet. However, based on the [Flet roadmap](https://flet.dev/roadmap), it doesn't appear that the functionality is available just yet.  
The anticipated timeframe extends to January 2024.

Answer (score 1):

Flet uses ResponsiveRow and borrows the idea of grid layout from the Bootstrap web framework. ResponsiveRow is "responsive" because it can adapt the size of its children to the changing size of the screen (page, window). col can be set to have a different value for specific "breakpoints". Breakpoints are called dimension ranges.

For more details I recommend reading the information on the [website](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/responsiverow/)